# viewControllers is empty array

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having a problem using the UITabBarController and can't seem to get anywhere... maybe someone has run into something similar. I have the typical Tab Bar + Navigation app and everything is working great, except when I access options in the More tab.

On any other tab, if I log:

```
NSLog(@"%@ \n %@",self.selectedViewController,[self.selectedViewController viewControllers]);
```

I get, for example:

```
2010-05-29 00:05:13.512 MD[9950:207] <UINavigationController: 0x4c35ad0>
(
    <MDViewController: 0x4c35910>,
    <Detalle: 0x9050e80>
)
```

If I access an element in the More tab, I get:

```
2010-05-29 00:05:13.512 MD[9950:207] <UINavigationController: 0x4c35ad0>
(
)
```

An empty viewControllers array? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Antonio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, it was simple:

the navigation stack goes into MoreNavigationController. So all I had to do was

```
[self.moreNavigationController viewControllers]
```

Antonio